# deploy alfresco 6.2 war in tomcat 8

Tags: alfresco, tomcat8

I want to install alfresco 6.2 war in windows server 2012 R2

I use Postres 11.4 and apache-tomcat-8.5.50 and jdk 1.8

I try to follows the steps in this link :

https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/tasks/alf-war-install.html

I download alfresco-content-services-community-distribution-6.2.0-ga.zip

I modify this file share.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context crossContext="true">
  <Resources>
    <PostResources base="C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\webapps\share\modules"
                   className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                   webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
  </Resources>
</Context>
```

alfreco.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context crossContext="true">
  <Resources>
    <PostResources base="C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\webapps\share\modules\platform"
                   className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                   webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
  </Resources>
</Context>
```

when I start alfesco I have this error :

```
03-Jan-2020 00:04:57.878 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml]
03-Jan-2020 00:04:58.659 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/alfresco]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:311)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:489)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:669)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.<init>(WebXmlParser.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1105)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:308)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.alfresco.xmlfactory.SAXParserFactoryXercesImpl could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:294)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/alfresco/util/log/log4j/SanitizingPatternLayout has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [org.alfresco.util.log.log4j.SanitizingPatternLayout])
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2398)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:855)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:797)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
        at org.alfresco.xmlfactory.FactoryHelper.<clinit>(FactoryHelper.java:44)
        at org.alfresco.xmlfactory.SAXParserFactoryXercesImpl.<clinit>(SAXParserFactoryXercesImpl.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 26 more
03-Jan-2020 00:04:58.691 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\conf\Catalina\localhost\alfresco.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/alfresco]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying those XML files is only necessary if you want to enable simple JAR modules. As the doc says, this is an optional step.

I recommend strongly against using simple JAR modules and instead believe you should use AMPs for everything.

So try it without modifying those two XML files.

Also, your log indicates you might not be using the correct version of the JDK. Make sure you are running OpenJDK (or Oracle) 11.0.1.